# Simple mysql select issue

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select all the duplicated row in my database. I have table below:

```
title     content
aa          hahaha
bb          weeeee
cc          dddddd
aa          ggggg
aa          ggggggee
dd          hhhhhhh
bb          ggggggg
```

my query is

```
select count(post_title) as total, content from post group by post_title
```

it will only show

```
 total        content
    3        hahaha
    2        weeeeee
```

but i want to show something like

```
total        content
aa          hahaha
aa          ggggg
aa          ggggggee
bb          weeeeeee
bb          geeeeeee
```

not sure what to do and I think it might be simple. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Select title, content
From table_name
Where title In
    (Select title From Table
     Group By title
     Having COUNT(*) > 1)
```

(from [Multiple NOT distinct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269605/multiple-not-distinct))

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, the SQL query should look like:

```
SELECT post_title, content
FROM post
GROUP BY post_title, content
```

Comment: it won't show all the duplicated title and contents. thanks though

Answer (score 0):

try with something like

```
SELECT total, content FROM post 
   WHERE id IN ( 
    SELECT id FROM post 
         GROUP BY post_title 
         HAVING count(post_title) > 1 
   )
```

Comment: why not? what is this query returning, and what do you need?

Comment: your query select id instead of title. plz see the accepted answer. :)