# Select non distinct rows from two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

My question is very similar to [Multiple NOT distinct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269605/multiple-not-distinct) only it deals with multiple columns instead of one. I have a table like so:

```
A B C
1 1 0
1 2 1
2 1 2
2 1 3
2 2 4
2 3 5
2 3 6
3 1 7
3 3 8
3 1 9
```

And the result should be:

```
A B C
2 1 2
2 1 3
2 3 5
2 3 6
3 1 7
3 1 9
```

Essentially, like the above question, removing all unique entries only where uniqueness is determined by two columns instead of one. I already tried various tweaks to the above answer but couldn't get any of them to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using SQL Server, so this is easier than in Access:

```
select A, B, C
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by A, B) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt > 1;
```

This use of `count(*)` is as a window function.  It is counting the number of rows with the same value of `A` and `B`.  The final `where` just selects the rows that have more than one entry.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks! Any clarification of what the OVER and the PARTITION BY statements are doing?

Comment: @1215drew-NWR- . . . These used for window functions, which are very useful.  Database documentation covers these pretty well (at least SQL Server and Oracle).  They are part of the standard and readily available (SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, DB2, for instance). I know I cover them in my book "Data Analysis Using SQL and Excel".  Basic SQL books don't usually cover this topic.

Comment: Thanks, I'll dig into the documentation a bit more, and maybe check out your book.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution with `EXISTS`

```sql
SELECT a, b, c 
  FROM Table1 t
 WHERE EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1 
    FROM Table1
   WHERE a =  t.a 
     AND b =  t.b
     AND c <> t.c
)
```

*It should be fast enough.*

Output:

```
| A | B | C |
-------------
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 | 5 |
| 2 | 3 | 6 |
| 3 | 1 | 7 |
| 3 | 1 | 9 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4384/2)** demo