# combining 3 tables where combination of 2 columns is not unique

Tags: sql, select, union

There are 3 (will be up to 6 in the future) tables with the same columns.

I need to unify them, i.e. union on same columns. In addition to this - rows shall not be unique, based on 2 column combination! There are a couple of examples on the net, but all of them show how to exclude unique column values based on WHERE **for one column**. In my case there are 2 columns (Col1 and Col2 combination).

Here are the schematics:

[image]

and

[image]

And here is how I imagined final query (for 3-tables) would look like:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
(
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION
SELECT * FROM table2
UNION
SELECT * FROM table3
)
GROUP BY
Col1, Col2
HAVING
COUNT (*) > 1
```

What would be a correct way?

**P.S. FYI single-column solutions**

[Multiple NOT distinct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269605/multiple-not-distinct)

[How to select non "unique" rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519582/how-to-select-non-unique-rows)

[How to Select Every Row Where Column Value is NOT Distinct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146304/how-to-select-every-row-where-column-value-is-not-distinct)

**EDIT:**

I have used the code from accepted answer and added additional search criteria:

```
  ON (SOUNDEX(Merged.[name_t1]) = SOUNDEX(Multiples.[name_t1]) OR Merged.[name_t1] LIKE '%' + Multiples.[name_t1] + '%' OR Multiples.[name_t1] LIKE '%' + Merged.[name_t1] + '%')
  AND (SOUNDEX(Merged.[name_t2]) = SOUNDEX(Multiples.[name_t2]) OR Merged.[name_t2] LIKE '%' + Multiples.[name_t2] + '%' OR Multiples.[name_t2] LIKE '%' + Merged.[name_t2] + '%')
```

**search col1 and col2:**

-by SOUNDEX

-by col1 like (col1 from other table)

-by (col1 from other table) like col1

Comment: What variety of SQL? MS-SQL, PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc? If you have the power of Common Table Expressions available to you, I daresay I could rustle up something.....

Comment: @AjVJsy That's a sqllite db

Comment: That's good, that allows a technique I get on with, according to http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html - you can use a double CTE approach. UNION ALL your tables together into the first CTE, have a second one GROUPED BY the Cols1&2 HAVING count>1, then in the main SELECT you can join between the two to return all rows from the first CTE that are in the 2nd. I can provide a skeleton outline in a few hours time if you need more..

Comment: @AjVJsy looking forward to it! The main idea is to union 3 or more tables together with the non-unique col1 and col2. After work I will try to dig more information on solution that you have proposed! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the basics of a CTE-based approach :

```
With Merged AS
(  -- CTE 1 : All Data in one table
 SELECT * FROM table1
  UNION ALL
 SELECT * FROM table2
  UNION ALL
 SELECT * FROM table3
) 
, Multiples AS
(  -- CTE 2 : Group by the fields in common
 SELECT   Col1, Col2
 FROM Merged
 GROUP BY Col1, Col2
 HAVING Count(*)>1 -- only want Groups of 2 or more
)
SELECT
  Merged.*
FROM Merged INNER JOIN Multiples
  -- Only return rows from Merged if they're in Multiples
   ON Merged.[Col1]=Multiples.[Col1]
  AND Merged.[Col2]=Multiples.[Col2]
```

Something like that works with my own example MS-SQL data, and it looks like SQLite syntax is the same. HTH!

Comment: thank you! i will prepare the test data today in the evening a do some tests

Comment: works like a charm! Except - I had to add additional conditions for select.. see the post update